# Tricky duplicate rows based on condition and add a counter in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where if a certain condition is met, I'd like to essentially create a duplicate of that row. **Row should be duplicated IF 'Date' = Q4.22 or > AND type = 'live'**
Also, for every duplicate created the 'unit' count should be updated to reflect this (grouped by id and Date)
**Once the duplicate is established, the unit count should reflect the new count based on the same id and Date.**

**Data**

```
   id   Date    set     type    unit    energy
   bb   Q4.22   l       live    l01     20
   bb   Q4.22   l       live    l02     20
   ba   Q3.22   l       non     l01     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       non     l01     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       live    l01     20
   cc   Q3.22   l       non     l01     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       live    l02     20
```

**Desired**

```
   id   Date    set     type    unit    energy
   bb   Q4.22   l       live    l01     20
   bb   Q4.22   l       live    l02     20
   bb   Q4.22   l       live    l03     20
   bb   Q4.22   l       live    l04     20
   ba   Q3.22   l       non     l01     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       non     l01     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       live    l01     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       live    l02     20
   cc   Q3.22   l       non     l01     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       live    l03     20
   aa   Q4.22   l       live    l04     20
```

**Doing**

```
pd.concat([df, df.loc[(df['Date'] == > 'Q4.22') & (df['live'] == 'live')]])
```

However, I still need to add  counter to the new duplicates that are created.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: In order to create the duplicate the following condition should be met. The Data column should be Q4.22 or later  and the type column should contain 'live' string

Comment: how is `'unit'` obtained in the first place and why is it a string `f'l{i:02d}'`?

Comment: @PierreD it is combination of the set 'l' the type and then the count for a given id and quarter (updated to lower case l)

Comment: there are several problems with this. I would have left `unit` to be a numerical value. Likewise, I would have left the `Date` to be a real date, or a `Period`. The way you select `... > 'Q4.22'` does not generalize, because it means "lexicographically greater than or equal to". Imagine your comparison period was Q1 2022 instead. `'Q3.1900' >= 'Q1.2022'`, but `Period('1900Q3') < Period('2022Q1')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. Convert your date column to timestamps
2. `concat` your original data with the filtered data
3. `groupby` to get the `cumcount` of "id" and "Date" and set the "unit" accordingly

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"].str.replace(r"(Q\d).(\d+)", r"\2-\1",regex=True))

output = pd.concat([df, df[df["Date"].ge(pd.Timestamp("2022-10-01"))&df["type"].eq("live")]], ignore_index=True)
output["unit"] = output["set"]+output.groupby(["id", "Date"]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(2)
output = output.sort_values("id", ignore_index=True)

#convert Date back to original format if needed
output["Date"] = output["Date"].dt.to_period("Q").astype(str).str.replace(r"\d\d(\d+)(Q\d)",r"\2.\1",regex=True)

>>> output
    id   Date set  type unit  energy
0   aa  Q4.22   l   non  l01      20
1   aa  Q4.22   l  live  l02      20
2   aa  Q4.22   l  live  l03      20
3   aa  Q4.22   l  live  l04      20
4   aa  Q4.22   l  live  l05      20
5   ba  Q3.22   l   non  l01      20
6   bb  Q4.22   l  live  l01      20
7   bb  Q4.22   l  live  l02      20
8   bb  Q4.22   l  live  l03      20
9   bb  Q4.22   l  live  l04      20
10  cc  Q3.22   l   non  l01      20
```

Answer (score 1):

First, as noted in the comments, we need to convert some of the df columns into more convenient types:

- `int` for `unit` (stripping any chars),
- `pd.Period` for the `Date`.

```py
df2 = df.assign(
    unit=df['unit'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int),
    period=df['Date'].str.replace(r'^(Q\d)\D*(\d+)$', r'\2\1', regex=True).apply(pd.Period)
)

>>> df2
   id   Date set  type  unit  energy  period
0  bb  Q4.22   l  live     1      20  2022Q4
1  bb  Q4.22   l  live     2      20  2022Q4
2  ba  Q3.22   l   non     1      20  2022Q3
3  aa  Q4.22   l   non     1      20  2022Q4
4  aa  Q4.22   l  live     1      20  2022Q4
5  cc  Q3.22   l   non     1      20  2022Q3
6  aa  Q4.22   l  live     2      20  2022Q4

>>> df2.dtypes
id               object
Date             object
set              object
type             object
unit              int64
energy            int64
period    period[Q-DEC]
dtype: object
```

With this done, now we can proceed with the logic of the question itself.

```py
ix_repeat = (df2['period'] >= pd.Period('2022-Q4')) & (df2['type'] == 'live')
r = df2.loc[ix_repeat]
r.assign(unit=r['unit'] + r.groupby(['id', 'period'])['unit'].transform(max))

>>> r
   id   Date set  type  unit  energy  period
0  bb  Q4.22   l  live     3      20  2022Q4
1  bb  Q4.22   l  live     4      20  2022Q4
4  aa  Q4.22   l  live     3      20  2022Q4
6  aa  Q4.22   l  live     4      20  2022Q4

# finally
df2 = pd.concat([df2, r])
```

Optional: bringing back unit into its weird string version:

```py
df2 = df2.assign(unit=df2['set'] + df2['unit'].astype(str).str.zfill(2))

>>> df2
   id   Date set  type unit  energy  period
0  bb  Q4.22   l  live  l01      20  2022Q4
1  bb  Q4.22   l  live  l02      20  2022Q4
2  ba  Q3.22   l   non  l01      20  2022Q3
3  aa  Q4.22   l   non  l01      20  2022Q4
4  aa  Q4.22   l  live  l01      20  2022Q4
5  cc  Q3.22   l   non  l01      20  2022Q3
6  aa  Q4.22   l  live  l02      20  2022Q4
0  bb  Q4.22   l  live  l03      20  2022Q4
1  bb  Q4.22   l  live  l04      20  2022Q4
4  aa  Q4.22   l  live  l03      20  2022Q4
6  aa  Q4.22   l  live  l04      20  2022Q4
```